# Set Socket.IO polling frequency?

Tags: socket.io

Is there any way to set (i. e. reduce) the polling frequency for Socket.IO (v4.4) when using the long polling transport? Either on the server or the client?

The long polling transport is described [in the documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/how-it-works/), and usually acts as a fallback (but can be explicitly set) when a WebSocket connection cannot be established:

> The bidirectional channel between the Socket.IO server (Node.js) and the Socket.IO client (browser, Node.js, or another programming language) is established with a WebSocket connection whenever possible, and will use HTTP long-polling as fallback.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No
Long answer:
Well that's not how Socket.io works.
It doesn't "poll"
That would defeat the whole purpose of increased performing and whatnot.
What socket.io does on the client is wait for the server to send data. It doesn't ask the server for it. Same thing to send messages.
And the exact same thing on the server.
Which is why you don't have to bother with the poll rate.

Comment: The docs say: *"The bidirectional channel between the Socket.IO server (Node.js) and the Socket.IO client (browser, Node.js, or another programming language) is established with a WebSocket connection whenever possible, and **will use HTTP long-polling as fallback."*** And the question is about the fallback. If Socket.IO uses WebSocket, there is no polling, of course.

Comment: I was writting something different to this but, I just realized, 
It's said it uses "long polling"
long-polling isn't continuously sending data at a certain frequency. It's just sending some data and waiting for reply. The reply is sent when a change occurs. 
And what your are thinking is that this is short-polling. 
Which is when you continuesly send data to and from the server but, Socket.io doesn't do that. So, you can't actually change it

Comment: To summarize, my above comment, "long-polling" is not "short-polling" and you are getting confused with both of them

Comment: Ok, you're right on long-polling. But if the server replies after approximately 50 ms (because of a new message emitted) but you only need an update every 500 ms, it would be nice if Socket.IO had the option to automatically buffer the messages and deliver around 10 of them together to the client.

Comment: It uses "HTTP long-polling as 'fallback'". Fallback, as defined by google dictionary means "an alternative plan that may be used in an emergency". Which means that when the socket.io connection fails, it uses long-polling. And, it's what socket.io primarily uses